# NO Animation Using Method overridePendingTransition();

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, animation

No animation Could be Seen On Switching Activity
1st Activity-------------- 2nd Activity
             No Animation
Here's The Snippet

```
    private void StartAnimations() {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);

    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                // Splash screen pause time
                while (waited < 3500) {
                    sleep(100);
                    waited += 100;
                }
                **Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in,R.anim.right_in);**

                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }

        }
    };
    splashTread.start();

}
```

Here's My Animation File

slide_left_in.xml

```
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"/>
<alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

slide_right_out.xml

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"/>
<alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

So Basically OverridePendingTransition Doesnt Do Anything

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one as I have worked with this one. Don't use AnimationUtils because in Activity, it needs only overridePendingTransition...

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SPLASH_TIME = 3000;
    AppPreference preference;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        preference=new AppPreference(getApplicationContext());

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(preference.getLoggedIn()){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LaunchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
                }


                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_TIME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first change the names in functions as 
`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in,R.anim.slide_right_in);`

instead of

`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in,R.anim.right_in);`

and Remove 
`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);`

Comment: No Change After all that Too
Any Other Solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
SplashScreen.this.finish();
```

before `overridePendingTransition()` and remove

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

Something Like This:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
SplashScreen.this.finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in,R.anim.right_in);
```

Comment: No Change Sir 
It's the same